# AngularJS custom directive for mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a custom directive because the first solution I came up with worked, but it seemed messy.

When the `tr` element has mouseenter I want to show the pencil icon, and when mouseleave occurs the pencil icon should hide again.

First solution: (this worked)

```
<tr ng-mouseenter="hoverEdit = !hoverEdit" ng-mouseleave="hoverEdit = !hoverEdit" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td><i ng-show="hoverEdit" class="fa fa-pencil"></i></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(user)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

I thought the `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` seemed to clutter up the `tr` element, so I want to create a directive...here is what I tried

directive solution (doesn't work)

```
Users.directive('showpencilhover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('mouseenter', function() {
                hoverEdit == !hoverEdit
            });

            element.on('mouseleave', function() {
                hoverEdit == !hoverEdit
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I believe the problem is that I can't just reference hoverEdit, so I'm not sure how to make this work. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can, you just have to preface it with `scope` (notice how `scope` is injected in the `link` function)

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('mouseenter', function() {
            scope.hoverEdit == !scope.hoverEdit
        });

        element.on('mouseleave', function() {
            scope.hoverEdit == !scope.hoverEdit
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm yeah this makes sense, I don't know why it's not working...I would just reference it as `<tr showpencilhover ng-repeat="user in users">` correct?

Comment: is `Users` initialized to your app? (`var Users = angular.module("myApp")` ?

Comment: sorry for the slow response, but yes, `Users` is initialized in the app

Comment: I created a test directive it see if it would even work, to ensure that its initializing, and it worked. I'm not sure why this solution isn't working. Here was the test directive: `Users.directive('test', function() { return { restrict: 'A', link: function(scope, element, attrs) { element.on('mouseover', function() { console.log('test'); }); }}});`

Comment: Also, when I `console.log(scope.hoverEdit)` undefined is returned